# Rating bar like android in codename one

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

I want to add Add Raring Bar in a Form of codename one like android.. But am afraid there is no GUI for to create in codename one.. Is there any other option for to create it..

[image: Rating Bar]

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=rating

Comment: @Jay Gajjar thanks for your Support.. but i need the rating bar in codename one tool..

Comment: @Jay Gajjar. No its not using html5,, where am using java in it..

Answer (score 2):

I think someone contributed a component like that on the [discussion forum](http://codenameone.com/discussion-forum.html) once, but I can't find the link.

It should be relatively simple to create using something like this (didn't test this code though):

```
Container starSelect = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
for(int iter = 0 ; iter < 5 ; iter++) {
    createStarButton(starSelect);
}

void createStarButton(final Container parent) {
    final CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
    cb.setToggle(true);
    cb.setIcon(unselectedStarIcon);
    cb.setPressedIcon(selectedStarIcon);
    cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            if(cb.isSelected()) {
                boolean selected = true;
                for(int iter = 0 ; iter < parent.getComponentCount() ; iter++) {
                    Component current = parent.getComponentAt(iter);
                    if(current == cb) {
                       selected = false;
                       continue;
                    }
                    ((CheckBox)cb).setSelected(selected);
                }
            }
         }
    });
    parent.addComponent(cb);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your support,, i have created the Rating bar format using this, but i can't rollover for to fill the rating bar with full and half full stars..

Comment: Just add a rollover icon as well.

Comment: but this doesn't act like as rating bar for me..  as i tried this, i need a roll over model as of the Native rating bar like android with empty, full & half full Stars..

Comment: Is this for a feature phone or non-touch device? If so just add a focus listener or a key listener and handle selection appropriately. The code above assumes touch device and should be easily adaptable/customizable to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'am not `iOS` developer but i can provide some links please try

1.[DLStarRating](https://github.com/dlinsin/DLStarRating)

2.[RatingBar](https://github.com/yuyedaidao/RatingBar)

3.[XLRatingBar](https://github.com/avincross/XLRatingBar)

4.[Sample RatingBar Project](http://ge.tt/10652Nk/v/0?c)

Comment: thanks for your effort.. but i need the rating bar in codename one tool.. that uses the java not xcode..