# CheckBox.setToggleButton doesn't exist

Tags: codenameone

i have been trying a code found  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600288/rating-bar-like-android-in-codename-one) to add rating bar but i got an error on

```
 cb.setToggleButton(
```

where the "setToggleButton" method didn't or doesn't exist anymore 
any idea if it has been update cause the post i tagged was back from 2014

Comment: I believe that post has a syntax error? It seems that setToggleButton method is missing the closing ")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method doesn't exist, it should be `setToggle(true)`. Notice in the linked post it just said `setToggleButton(` without even a closing bracket. Since this was written a while back I'm guessing I just switched a desktop to check the method name and got distracted then forgot to fix that. Hazards of blind coding without the comfort of an IDE.

@devcrp actually wrote the correct answer before but unfortunately he deleted it. If he undeletes it his answer should be accepted.

Comment: there's a little problem where the checkbox containing the stars is displayed on the Y axis ,  i tried changing this "Container starSelect = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS); " to X_AXIS , but it changed nothing and the stars keep showing under each other

Comment: Add that label to a different container and add the star label container to that container. In that container you can use whatever layout you want.